# Check if a specific app is running in the background

Tags: android, usagestatsmanager

I need to know when a specific app is in the background (not foreground).

I was able to get package name of all the applications running in the background with [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45213494):

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
// Process running
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    UsageStatsManager mUsageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager)getSystemService(USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    // We get usage stats for the last 10 seconds
    List<UsageStats> stats = mUsageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, time - 1000*10, time);
    // Sort the stats by the last time used
    if(stats != null) {
        SortedMap<Long,UsageStats> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<Long,UsageStats>();
        for (UsageStats usageStats : stats) {
            mySortedMap.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(),usageStats);
            Log.d("RunningAppProcessInfo","Package name : "+usageStats.getPackageName());
        }

    }
}
```

But now how do I check if the specific app is on the list or not?

Thanks

Comment: Would `usageStats.getPackageName() == "AppName"` be reliable for this? I wonder...

Answer (score -1):

If you want to check Specific Package than check below code I have added code in below method.

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
// Process running
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    UsageStatsManager mUsageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager)getSystemService(USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    // We get usage stats for the last 10 seconds
    List<UsageStats> stats = mUsageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, time - 1000*10, time);
    // Sort the stats by the last time used
    if(stats != null) {
        SortedMap<Long,UsageStats> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<Long,UsageStats>();
        for (UsageStats usageStats : stats) {
            mySortedMap.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(),usageStats);
            Log.d("RunningAppProcessInfo","Package name : "+usageStats.getPackageName());

        if(usageStats.getPackageName().equals("package name")) {
          Log.d("Package ","Package name : Success");
         }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works. But it could be that the code I provided is incorrect, because the list also includes apps that do not run in the background, and even an app that I deleted!
Do I need to change anything in the code?

Comment: I was able to do this with [queryEvents](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38971472/18769941). Thanks.

Comment: boolean isNamedProcessRunning(String processName){
 if (processName == null) 
  return false;

 ActivityManager manager = 
    (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
 List<RunningAppProcessInfo> processes = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
 for (RunningAppProcessInfo process : processes)
 {
    if (processName.equals(process.processName))
    {
        return true;
    }
 }
 return false;
}

Comment: Check above code if you want to get packages that are running in background

Comment: Thanks. But for Lollipop and above it only works for [current application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30619349/18769941), and I need to check for another application.

Comment: I was able to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71835401/18769941) with queryEvents, but only for foreground, without background.